# minify css using inline imports in webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, import

We have lot of pages and lots of stylesheets. We wanted to inline some critical styles on some components to avoid network requests; I'd achieved the requirement by using `style-loader` with [inline import](https://v4.webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline) in `webpack 4` like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./style.sass";
import FancyButton from "components/UIkit/FancyButton";
```

to: (`!!` at the beginning will disable all configured loaders)

```js
import React from "react";
import "!!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!./style.sass";
import FancyButton from "components/UIkit/FancyButton";
```

this works fine and injects the `scss` into `<style></style>` tag; **BUT** in won't minfiy `css`.
I need a way to minify them too; preferably using inline import commands, magic comments or something like this:

```js
!style-loader!require('mini-css-extract-plugin').loader!css-loader!less-loader!./style.less
```

our `webpack` config is *ejected* version `create-react-app` with slight modification to meet our needs. and for normal `imports` it works perfectly fine; and minifies all the `css`s using `MiniCssExtractPlugin`. but Inlining imports won't follow the default pipeline and hence no minification.

---

I also welcome other suggestions to inline critical styles; (consider they can be `.scss`, `.less`, `.module.scss`)
excluding this way:

- [Inline CSS using Webpack](https://medium.com/@kilgarenone/inline-css-using-webpack-bb0d47119c04)